# Asp .Net Identity default claims added after login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have noticed that after a user registers and logins to my website some default claims are being added that are not in the database.

[image]

As in the picture we have `nameidentifier`, `name` and `SecurityStamp` which are not in my database and I guess they are added on sign in. I need to prevent the name claim from being added as it seems to be overriding the claim with claim type `name` that i add to database on registration for a user.

This is how i add claims on registration for a user. (Maybe I am using wrong claim for users Firstname?)

[image]

So to sum it up can i turn off the default claims being added or should i use different claim type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClaimTypes.Name` is generally used for the username/login name

`ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` is the user Id.

Use `ClaimTypes.GivenName` for Forename

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes(v=vs.110).aspx

There's also nothing stopping you creating your own claim types if there isn't a built in one that matches your need (e.g. FullName)

Comment: So `ClaimTypes.UserName` and `ClaimTypes.Name` both refer to the same thing? I was thinking about using `ClaimTypes.GivenName` too, but wasn't sure if that the right claim type to use to store users firstname.

Comment: I'm not seeing a `ClaimTypes.UserName`. Is that a custom claim? If so it seems redundant given `ClaimTypes.Name` exists.

Comment: GivenName and ForeName are interchangeable. GivenName is more correct as "Eastern-Format" names are family name first and given names after.

Comment: My bad it seems there isn't `ClaimTypes.UserName` (I'm sure there was...) [MSDN ClaimTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes(v=vs.110).aspx). I guess I will go with `ClaimTypes.GivenName` thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> This is how i add claims on registration for a user. (Maybe I am using wrong claim for users Firstname?)

You don't need to add the claims yourself, you can use `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>` to do it for you:

1. Define in your controller injected dependencies:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

// Inject the following
UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions
```

2. In action do this:

```cs
var factory = new UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser>(userManager, identityOptions);
var claimsPrincipal = await factory.CreateAsync(user);
```

If for some reason you can't use the factory, you can consult the latest identities from [`ClaimsIdentityOptions`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/64c37113aafcbad73113b7cb86f86129e8839963/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/ClaimsIdentityOptions.cs) and from the [`UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/64c37113aafcbad73113b7cb86f86129e8839963/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs) source codes.